# Как передать ArrayList<Model> в intent.putExtra?

Tags: android

Вообщем есть список `ArrayList` который реализовует модель `Model`. Как такой список передать в `intent`. Там вроде есть только для `ArrayList<String>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Model implements Serializable {
...
}
```

И теперь вы сможете туда положить этот `ArrayList<Model>`

Доставать так:
`ArrayList<Model> modelList = (ArrayList<Model>)intent.getSerializableExtra ("name");`

Comment: А как его потом вытянут ?

Comment: @user186301, обновил ответ